# php touch modification date, access date not clear from php.net

Tags: php, file

I am able to touch a file date created no problem.

But i want set access date or modified date

http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php

```
$access = $date; //now
```

> **atime**
>   If present, the access time of the given filename is set to the value of 
>   atime. Otherwise, it is set to the value passed to the time parameter. If 
>   neither are present, the current system time is used.

OK, where do you put that? `atime`?

```
touch($filename, $access, atime)
```

tried for hours

I read

```
bool touch ( string $filename [, int $time = time() [, int $atime ]] )
```

but seems overcomplicated

I read the examples on php.net but not have `atime` working

Comment: What is you actual code and how do you define the `$atime` variable? Generally the `$atime` is optional parameter if set then the time is applied.

Comment: atime would be a stanard Epoch time. but thats not the point i am trying to get touch to set the atime or mtime not creation time by default.

Comment: According to the documentation `touch` does not modify the creation time on existing files. Only modification and access time is set if requested by optional params.

Answer (score 2):

`atime` is used to change the "last access time of file":

With no parameter:

```
$filename = "test.test";
touch($filename);
echo filemtime($filename), PHP_EOL; // 1521149547 // now 
echo fileatime($filename), PHP_EOL; // 1521149547 // now
```

With `time`:

```
$filename = "test.test";
touch($filename, time() - 3600);
echo filemtime($filename), PHP_EOL; // 1521145965 // 1 hour ago
echo fileatime($filename), PHP_EOL; // 1521145965 // same as mtime
```

With `atime`:

```
$filename = "test.test";
touch($filename, time() - 3600, time() - 7200);
echo filemtime($filename), PHP_EOL; // 1521145974 // 1 hour ago
echo fileatime($filename), PHP_EOL; // 1521142374 // 2 hours ago
```

If you don't want to change the "modification date", you can use (this will not change the creation time):

```
touch($filename, filemtime($filename), $accesstime);
```

Comment: touch($filename, time() - $accesstime); woudl that work/

Comment: @NanceS I think you want `touch($filename, time(), $accesstime);`. Isn't it? If you want to the "modifed time" at "now", and set the "access time" with your timestamp.

Comment: @NanceS If you don't want to change "modification date", use: `touch($filename, filemtime($filename), $accesstime);`.

Comment: not permitted, i tried to chown all files as apache owner $path = $dir;
$user = "apache";
echo $path;
exec("sudo chown -R $user $path");

Comment: @NanceS Right. Don't forget to close your question if an answer solves your problem. Thanks for all your answerers and future readers :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP documentation, parameters within square brackets [] are optional.
You can call touch with just the filename:

```
touch($filename);
```

Which will change the  access and midification time to the current systemtime.
If you want to set it to a specific time, you would call:

```
touch($filename, $time);
```

If you want to set the modified time to a different value than access time, you would call:

```
touch($filename, $modifiedTime, $accessTime);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: touch($filename, $accessTime);   sets it as creationed time

Comment: @NanceS You can't just skip arguments.  Even if the second argument is optional, if you want to set the 3rd argument, you _must_ pass a value for the second.

Comment: touch($filename, $modifiedTime, $accessTime);  sets accestime but sets modfied time as nothing and it ereases the modified time i dont want to erease it

Answer (score 0):

Now I see,

`atime` key word in the list of *Parameters* is definition of the `$atime` variable in the *Description*

So in your example of `touch($filename, $access, atime)` you are missing the dollar char.

Correct usage is:

```
touch($filename, $access, $atime);
```

Update:

To edit only access time then set the modification time the same as the file actually has:

```
 touch($filename, filemtime($filename), $atime);
```

Comment: atime is a paramater so i did not put the dollar sign, but i wont to set the accesstime (atime) without touching the modification or creation date

Comment: Just updated my answer to keep original access time of the file